# Handling onPress from model generated buttons

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a model which I simplify for the purpose of this question

```
MyModel(a:0, b:0, c:0) //a b c are integers
```

Now I need to generate buttons from this model so I've created a new class which takes that model as a parameter and generates buttons

```
class Panel extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyModel model;

  const Panel({this.model});

  List<Widget> _buildContent() {
    final list = [
      {'a': model.a},
      {'b': model.b},
      {'c': model.c}
    ];
    List<Widget> l = [];
    list.forEach((element) {
      l.add(FlatButton(child: Text(element.keys.first), onPressed: () {}));
    });
    return l;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: _buildContent(),
        ));
  }
}
```

and in my main class, I'm just calling it like this

```
Panel(model: myModel);
```

I'm trying to find the neatest way to handle presses of these buttons, each button should update its element at +1 on each press and send the updated model back to the main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for your Panel to provide a callback when the model changes. Then you can change the model used in your application. Note the "onChange" callback added to the Panel that in the App calls `setState` to actually change the model.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Model {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  final int c;

  const Model({this.a, this.b, this.c});
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Model model = Model(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Current Model: a:${model.a}, b:${model.b}, c: ${model.c}')),
        body: Center(
          child: Panel(
            model: model, 
            onChange: (changedModel) => setState(() => model = changedModel)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PanelButton {
  final String text;
  final Model Function() onClick;

  const PanelButton(this.text, this.onClick);
}

class Panel extends StatelessWidget {
  final Model model;
  final void Function(Model) onChange;

  const Panel({@required this.model, this.onChange});

  List<Widget> _buildContent() {
    final list = [
      PanelButton('a', () => Model(a: model.a + 1, b: model.b, c: model.c)),
      PanelButton('b', () => Model(a: model.a, b: model.b + 1, c: model.c)),
      PanelButton('c', () => Model(a: model.a, b: model.b, c: model.c + 1)),
    ];

    return list
        .map((x) => FlatButton(
            child: Text(x.text), onPressed: () => _raiseOnChange(x.onClick())))
        .toList();
  }

  void _raiseOnChange(Model model) {
    if (onChange != null) {
      onChange(model);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: _buildContent(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I actually already managed it by my self literally a minute before you post the answer.. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:

1. Rather than following model thing, you can make a `Global Variable`, which has a `dictionary/hasmap`. Make a file named as `globals.dart` and do this

```
/* 
  This is the primary util for maintaining 
  all the Global values/variables
*/
library globals;

//This is your variable
Map<String, dynamic> mydata = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0};
```

Now, you can access global value anywhere in any file, by just importing the `globals.dart` file like `import '{path}/globals.dart'`

2. Now in your `Panel`, we can access it, and do the increment of the item as per your will

```
import '{path}/globals.dart' as globals

class Panel extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> _buildContent() {
      List<Widget> l = [];
      
      // No list declaration, direct items access
      globals.mydata.forEach((key, value) {
        l.add(
         FlatButton(
           child: Text(key), 
           onPressed: (key) {
               //on pressed you just increment when it is hit for the key elem
               globals.mydata[key] += 1;
           }
        ));
    });
    return l;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: _buildContent(),
        ));
  }
}
```

3. Final step, now when you hit on the button, you get updated HasMap, which is globally accessible, so you can call the `Panel()`, no params required. And when you want to check the updated value just print it

```
import '{path}/globals.dart' as globals

Panel()

// This will give out the updated data if the button is hit else {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
print(globals.mydata)
```

This is the cleanest way I can think for you in this case.

Comment: When you find yourself using globals, something is off. Global variables are not a good idea for so many reasons. See [Why is global state so evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: I'm not using globals but still your answer is interesting but because of the 'evil' reason mentioned by @nvoigt I mark his answer as answered

Comment: Yeah @nvoigt, that is why I mentioned **in this case**, however, I am glad, for your feedback. Will definitely take a look at that

Comment: Yeah @delmin, you must always follow the best approach, in order to learn the best thing :)